# Returning a pointer to a boxed value from a collection in Rust

Tags: pointers, rust, borrow-checker

I have a collection of boxed object:

```
objects : Vec<Box<MyObject>>
```

I have a function that needs to return a *mut MyObject, and it pretty much look like this.

```
    for object in self.objects.iter()
    {
        if object.name == new_object_name
        {
            return &mut *object;
        }
    }

    return std::ptr::null_mut();
```

But I am getting an error during compilation on return line:

```
expected struct `MyObject`, found struct `Box`
```

Comment: what does sub_dir hold here? The code seems kind of incomplete to me

Comment: This question clearly lacks of a minimal reproducible example. Currently, we can't help you more than repeating what the error message says: check your types.

Comment: @RishadBaniya that was a mistake on my part it should have been object there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to dereference twice, as `object` is `&Box<MyObject>`, and use `iter_mut()` because you want a mutable reference:

```rust
for object in self.objects.iter_mut() {
    if object.name == new_object_name {
        return &mut **object;
    }
}

return std::ptr::null_mut();
```